# Is it possible to prevent sensitive input data like username and password from appearing in Fridump memory dump?

Tags: javascript, react-native

We're testing what is being available in a Fridump memory dump after we log in our application, and we can find the username and password in the file. We're not storing the username or password in Redux, AsyncStorage or any other storage and it is only available in the RAM of the application.

Now I am being asked to completely prevent that, however, from what I've read and seen this seems to not be possible because of JavaScript's automatic garbage collector.

Am I correct in my assumption, and is there any documentation which I could present in order to support my argument?

Comment: You could refer them to this question: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/170032 and https://security.stackexchange.com/q/189808

Comment: Interesting question. Have you tried to replace username/password with anything (e.g. empty string) right after credentials were used and user is logged in? I assume that with such approach, when GC will run next time it will collect credentials object (or whatever you have there) but with dummy/empty data already, so the actual inputs will not get into GC. 
It's just my assumption, moreover I don't know exactly how your app works, but I hope you understood the idea.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you're correct on your assumption, you don't have direct control over [JavaScript garbage collector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_management). You can't make sure that the memory is freed.

However, what you *can* control is everything server sided, so use secure storage mechanisms and make sure you can encrypt any sensitive data. Make sure to not just encrypt it on storage, but also on transport.

Comment: The thing is that I am not storing the username and password anywhere. The only place where the password and username are stored is in the respective useState variables while the user is typing them in the input.